# .Qt : Blocking QObject from receiving signals

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way of telling a `QObject` to temporarily ignore all incoming signals?

I know there exist a "`QObject::BlockSignals(bool)`" which if set to true prevents `QObject` from sending signals out.

I want the functionality kind of in reverse, I want the event queue to simply not queue or if it does ignore calling slots when it's time to while slots are blocked.

In another words I'm asking for a "`QObject::BlockSlots(bool)`".

Comment: If you need such solution - it means that you have bad design. You may introduce a `bool disableSlotsFlag` inside your class and check it in every slot. Other approach is to disconnect all slots and connect it again when nesessary. Btw, you may find a lot of usefull code [there](https://www.kdab.com/development-resources/qt-tools/gammaray/).

Comment: @Kamran, if your final goal is to stop queue processing in slots .. what THEN is the use of firing signals !! simply block signals .. and its a bad practice to do workarounds INSIDE slots! yes this is bad design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is (to my knowledge) no inbuilt way to (temporarily) turn off the receiving/processing of signals for a QObject.

It would probably be easiest to implement a check-and-ignore functionality directly in the relevant functions:

```
void doStuff()
{
    if (ignoreSignals)
        return;
    // Actual functionality here...
}
```

If you are unable to change the code you might consider disconnect()ing the relevant signal-slot-function (or the entire object), and re-connect()ing it later.

Alternatively you might implement a "Filter" object to which other Objects connect (instead of directly connecting to your original Object) and which implements the check-and-ignore functionality mentioned earlier, only forwarding (i.e. emit()ing) the signal if the filter is not active.

Comment: To build on the "Filter" suggestion, one way to pull this off is to connect the original `QObject` to a [Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) object that inherits form `QObject` and whose role is to pass around signals.  To toggle signals on and off, just call [`QObject::blockSignals()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals).

Comment: this is how i decided to handle things for now, but it gets annoying having to add this flag thing to every slot in the object and it's children an so on .